# "The server was unable to save the form at this Time. Please try again."

Tags: sharepoint-server, 2016, 401, ntlm

I have an issue whenever I try or other users try to create a new list in Announcements or in any other part of the sharepoint we recieve error

> "The server was unable to save the form at this Time. Please try again.".

Upon investigating further we have found out that this only happens on Chrome or Edge or any other Browser except Internet Explorer. On Internet Explorer, the site works correctly.

In the ULS logs I can see

> 401 Unauthorized error.

I have tried everything recommended on this site and from google but nothing works.
I am using anonymouse access and NTLM Auth.

SharePoint 2016 Server

Any tips?

Comment: Is there anything on the page that isn't available to anonymous access users?

Comment: Anonymous access is only enabled because of one plugin that is being used Word-AddIn.
Rest of the site is locked for users that are invited only.

Comment: Are you authenticated when the error occurs? Could you provide more information, logs etc? It's quite difficult to understand the potential causes with limited information.

Comment: Yes I am, unfortunately in the ULS logs all I can see is 401 Unauthorized. Well basically users can't add new lists or edit them in Chrome and Edge, everything works fine in Internet Explorer

Comment: The 401 error should have a stack trace in the logs. It sounds like misconfiguration of anonymous access but difficult to help with the limited details in the question.

Comment: For now I recommended users to use Edge in Internet Explorer mode and it works as a charm no issues. Maybe I suspect that this is some compatibility issue with SharePoint 2016

Comment: Unlikely to be a compatibility issue, SharePoint 2016 supports those browsers: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/install/browser-support-planning-2016-2019

Comment: I looked again at ULS logs and I can see nothing but only 401 error nothing else that could explain why there is that error

Comment: Likely to be misconfiguration of anonymous access, the majority of orgs are using Chrome/Edge with SharePoint now that IE is officially out of support. You'll need to look further at your configuration.

Comment: I have checked everything in the Anonymous Access both in SharePoint and IIS everything is setup according to instructions. However I have noticed that if I turn off anonymous access there is no more 403 but rather I get error Too many requests and still nothing is created

Answer (score 0):

This issue is mainly related to the user permission, You can solve this permission issue by either

- Giving that user/group at least read access to the site level.
- Or, you can create a new permission level which is same as limited access but with the additional permission of

> Use Remote Interfaces  –  Use SOAP, Web DAV, the Client Object Model
> or SharePoint Designer interfaces to access the Web site.

> Read more at **[The server was unable to save the form at this time SharePoint 2016](https://spgeeks.devoworx.com/the-server-was-unable-to-save-the-form-at-this-time-please-try-again-in-sharepoint-2013/)**

Comment: Created limited access with the permission Use Remote Inferfaces and still not working.

Comment: However everything is working fine in Internet Explorer mode

Comment: It seems a compatibility issue, which kind of customization you are using?

Comment: If by customization you mean some Site Features I have active few of them Following Content, Custom Feature for backend (Word-AddIn), Team Collaboration Lists and Workflow Task Content Type